# FirebaseRecycler doesn't retrieve list with a String in the DatabaseReference

Tags: android, firebase

The code that I will show next, I have been using it since always and now this error appears:

```
   com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.aplicacion.vivaluganoapp.ar.Model.UserPedido
```

com.aplicacion.vivaluganoapp.ar.Model.UserPedido its a java class

code:

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_comprobar_pedido);

        currentUserID = Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.getTelefono();

        ordersList =  findViewById(R.id.pedidorecycler);
        ordersList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        ordersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Usuarios").child(currentUserID).child("Pedidos");
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<UserPedido> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<UserPedido>()
                .setQuery(ordersRef, UserPedido.class)
                .build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UserPedido, UserProductViewHolder> adapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UserPedido, UserProductViewHolder>(options) {
                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserProductViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull UserPedido model) {
                        holder.userName.setText("Nombre: " + model.getNombre());
                        holder.userPhoneNumber.setText("Numero de Telefono: " + model.getTelefono());
                        holder.userTotalPrice.setText("Monto Total: " + model.getMontoTotal() + " ARS");
                        holder.userDateTime.setText("Orden: " + model.getTiempo() + "    " + model.getHora());
                        holder.userShippingAddress.setText("Direccion de Envio o Retiro: " + model.getDireccion() + ", " + model.getCiudad());
                        holder.userBirthday.setText("Cumpleaños:" + model.getCumpleaños());
                        holder.userInfoExtra.setText("Informacion Extra: " + model.getInformacionExtra());


                        holder.ShowOrdersBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                String uID = getRef(position).getKey();

                                Intent intent = new Intent(comprobarPedidoActivity.this, adminUserProductsActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("uid", uID);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });

                        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[]
                                        {
                                                "Si",
                                                "No"
                                        };
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(comprobarPedidoActivity.this);
                                builder.setTitle("Pedido");

                                builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {

                                        if(i == 0)
                                        {
                                            String uID = getRef(position).getKey();

                                            RemoverPedido(uID);

                                        }
                                        if(i == 1)
                                        {

                                            finish();
                                        }

                                    }
                                });

                                builder.show();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public UserProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.pedidos_layout, viewGroup, false);
                        return new UserProductViewHolder(view);
                    }
                };
        ordersList.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();
    }
    public static class UserProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView userName, userPhoneNumber, userTotalPrice, userDateTime, userShippingAddress, userBirthday, userInfoExtra;
        public Button ShowOrdersBtn;

        public UserProductViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);

            userName =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.pedido_nombre_usuario);
            userPhoneNumber =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.pedido_telefono_usuario);
            userTotalPrice =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.pedido_precio_total);
            userDateTime =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.pedido_tiempo_hora);
            userShippingAddress =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.pedido_direccion_city);
            ShowOrdersBtn =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.mostrar_todos_productos_btn);
            userBirthday = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pedido_cumpleaños);
            userInfoExtra = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pedido_info_extra);


        }
    }
```

the error is  located here:

```
ordersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Usuarios").child(currentUserID).child("Pedidos");
```

Every time I put the String currentUserID (which is the reference of its user ID in the database) I see the error mentioned above.
It's weird because I always use the same code to do that operation and I have not changed anything except for adding currentUserID (which I've added in other Java Classes and
 worked perfect).
Why does not that code work for me now and how could it be solved?

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Since your trying to use `UserPedido` class to get the data, you need to change the reference to

```
ordersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Usuarios").child(currentUserID)
```

If this won't solve the problem. Please share your database structure